# A shortcut to convert classes into records in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, c#-record-type

If I have the following class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to quickly convert it to a `record` type:

```
public record Foo(string Code, string Description, DateTime? EffectiveDate);
```

Is there a way to do that quickly? the built-in quick actions menu in VS19 doesn't seem to offer this.

Answer (score 4):

dotnet developers are working on that according to this issue [classtorecode](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/47598)

Answer (score 3):

You can try "Convert to positional record" in VS 2022 after clicking the class and then the screwdriver on the left.

Answer (score -1):

MappingGenerator plugin (for VisualStudio and Rider) contains 'Convert type to record' refactoring https://docs.mappinggenerator.net/refactorings/convert-type-to-record/

DISCLAIMER: I'm the author of MappingGenerator. The aforementioned refactoring belongs to paid features.